# how do I position a div based on percentage away from other divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have an iframe inside a div. I want to control how far away (top, bottom, width and height) based on other divs instead of just pixels. (basically make it responsive)

Im assuming this is a percentage calculation based on the other elements, but I don't know how to achieve this.

```
<div class ="framed">
  <iframe frameborder="0" 
    style="height: 100%; 
    overflow:scroll; 
    width: 100%" 
    src="localhost/wordpress2018/test" marginheight="1" marginwidth="1" 
    name="frame" 
    id="framemain" 
    seamless="seamless" scrolling="no" 
    frameborder="0"    
    allowtransparency="true">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

The reason I need to do it this way is because there are other divs created by the wordpress theme that I cannot adjust.

Also cheat question
I want it to scroll, but if I remove the scroll, I wont be able to scroll. How do I let it scroll when there is no scroll bar?

Comment: Is this like your other question where you said the iframe source would be from another domain? Also not clear what your dimension criteria should be based on.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I exactly understand the question, but a basic approach is to look up the WP div tag's location.

```
pos = $('wp-div').position();
// pos.top is Y 
// pos.left is X
```

Compare that to your desired page location and adjust your div accordingly.

```
$("#my-div").css({top: newY, left: newX, position:'absolute'});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, I can look at position this way, however the desired effect would be to be responsive. So by it being absolute, I don't see how it will be responsive.

Comment: The absolute position is calculated during initial display, or a browser resize event. The positioning can also be relative to another div like a parent, if so desired. By handling the resize, it should provide responsive-like repositioning.